# How to run code on a Virtual Computer?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, python

I have written a code in Python that takes a very long time to run. I am still looking into ways to make it faster; however, the code is used for simulations of Quantum Mechanical systems, meaning, it will take a long time no matter how hard I try to optimize the code (days, possibly weeks, at least with my own specs).

I was wondering whether it is possible to run it in a virtual computer. I have been looking into the Virtual Machines by Microsoft Azure but I am not sure whether that's what I am looking for.

To be clear, I would want to run a code on Jupyter Notebook, as well as install some special packages that allow me to do my quantum simulations (Qutip). Can the pre-mentioned virtual machine help me do this and if not, is there something else I could use?

Thank you!

Comment: Depending on how secret your code is, it might also be worth submitting a question on the code review stackexchange - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - to see if they have any performance suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code on Azure machines in the cloud is an option, but it is typically not a free option. That being said, I occasionally see offers to try Azure for a limited period of time.

See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free

If you are thinking of running your code on a virtual machine that is installed on your own computer, that would probably be slower than running the code in your host operating system.

Comment: I don't know of Azure, but you can use AWS in limited scope (but still usable) free for one year, if you are a new user: https://aws.amazon.com/free/